# Bootstrap 4 Carousel images not centering

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, flask

I've tried ***multiple*** StackOverflow answers and other sites to try to get the images in my carousel to be centered and none of them have worked. I'm not sure what to do, so I'll post my code and I'll try to help out as needed.

I am using Flask as the webserver, so there will be the `{{ variable }}` parts in my code.

HTML:

```html
<div class="c-wrapper">
  <div class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel" id="next">
    <div class="carousel-inner" id="inner">
      <div class="carousel-item active item" style="height: 500px; width: 500px;">
        <img class="d-block w-100" src="{{ url_for('static', filename='img/Logo7.png') }}" alt="Slide">
      </div>
    </div>
    <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#next" role="button" data-slide="prev">
      <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
      <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
    </a>
    <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#next" role="button" data-slide="next">
      <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
      <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
  var arr = JSON.parse('{{ cards | tojson }}')
  var i;
  for (i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    var imagelink = arr[i].imagelink
    document.getElementById("projects").innerHTML += '<div class="card text-white bg-dark" style="width: 18rem;"><img class="card-img-top" src="' + imagelink + '" alt="logo" style="width: 18rem"><div class="card-body"><h5 class="card-title">' + arr[i].title + '</h5><p class="card-text">' + arr[i].text + '</p><a href="' + arr[i].link + '" class="btn btn-success">Visit</a></div></div>'
  }
  var arr2 = JSON.parse('{{ carousel | tojson }}')
  var i2;
  for (i2 = 0; i2 < arr2.length; i2++) {
    var imagelink2 = arr2[i2].imagelink
    document.getElementById("inner").innerHTML += '<div class="carousel-item item" style="height: 500px; width: 500px;"><img class="d-block w-100" src="' + imagelink2 + '" alt="Slide"></div>'
  }
</script>
<style type="text/css">
  .c-wrapper {
    width: 80%;
    /* for example */
    margin: auto;
  }
  
  .carousel img {
    margin: auto;
  }
</style>
```

Comment: Where does `style="height: 500px; width: 500px;"` come from?

Comment: @ksav What....?

Comment: It's an inline style given to `.carousel-item`... Did you write it?

Comment: @ksav Yes, I did.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove inline styles on `carousel-item`

```css
.c-wrapper {
  width: 80%;
  /* for example */
  margin: auto;
}

.carousel img {
  margin: auto;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


<div class="c-wrapper">
  <div class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel" id="next">
    <div class="carousel-inner" id="inner">

      <div class="carousel-item active item">
        <img class="d-block w-100" src="https://picsum.photos/500/500" alt="Slide">
      </div>

      <div class="carousel-item item">
        <img class="d-block w-100" src="https://picsum.photos/500/500" alt="Slide">
      </div>

      <div class="carousel-item item">
        <img class="d-block w-100" src="https://picsum.photos/500/500" alt="Slide">
      </div>


    </div>
    <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#next" role="button" data-slide="prev">
      <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
      <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
    </a>
    <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#next" role="button" data-slide="next">
      <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
      <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This works, but is it possible to set the size and have it in the middle still?

Comment: Don't you already set the size on the wrapper with `width: 80%`?